# Calculating standard deviation of a channel in opencv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to calculate the ratio between two colors like R and Green, the Input is a camera image using opencv retrieved right now I'm getting NAN if if there are correct input data

```
def slidingMovingAverageWindow(x,y, windowLength):
     xS = pd.Series(x)
     yS = pd.Series(y)
     stdX = xS.rolling(window = windowLength).std()
     stdY = yS.rolling(window=windowLength).std()

     ratio = np.sqrt(stdX/stdY)
     return ratio
def compute_ippg(signal): # using color chorme
    B, G, R = cv2.split(signal)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', B)

    # convert to chrome key
    xs = 0.77 * R[2,:] - 0.51 * G[1,:]
    ys = 0.77 * R[2,:] + 0.51 * G[1,:] - 0.77 * B[0,:]
    a = slidingMovingAverageWindow(xs, ys, 2)
    iPPG = xs - a* ys;
    return iPPG
```

Window is 2, you can test on any image that you want to get the ratio between R and G.

The following line has the issue

```
ratio = np.sqrt(stdX/stdY) of NaN
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Right now I'm getting NAN if if there are correct input data"?

Comment: I don't know what image you are reading, but is it possible that all Green channel values are the same? This way the std would be zero, which would lead to a nan in the division